# Retrieving the organization of a user in Stormpath in .Net Core?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, identity, claims-based-identity, stormpath

I have an application setup with the Stormpath middleware for authentication. I also have my account setup to use the group per organization model. It appears to login and everything, but I'm struggling with finding a reasonable way to get the organizations ID or name base on the user that's logged in.

With the Stormpath.SDK.Account reference, I can do something like:

```
private readonly IAccount _account;
var name = _account.FullName;
```

I'd expect something similar to be available to retrieve the organization but I'm not finding anything in their SDK reference. So far I've tried:

Retrieving the organization from my claim. [This looks like it'll be available via the "onk" claim](https://docs.stormpath.com/rest/product-guide/latest/idsite.html#using-id-site-via-language), but I'm not seeing that as an option when looking at _claim's properties from the following code:

```
ClaimsPrincipal _claim = new ClaimsPrincipal(User.Identity);
            var OrganizationId = _claim.FindFirst("onk").Value;
```

I'm also not seeing a way to retrieve the organization out of the header. It [appears that Host is available in the header](https://docs.stormpath.com/dotnet/api/html/P_Stormpath_SDK_Http_HttpHeaders_Host.htm), but the SDK for Core doesn't seem to allow me to get that.

Ideally, I'd like the user to be able to login without specifying their tenant as a subdomain or a field in the login form. Since it will go through my organization stores in order, I'd expect that to be feasible.

Any ideas on what I'm missing?

Comment: This is actually a use case I'm speccing out and working on right now (I'm the author of the Stormpath SDK). Just so I understand your case correctly: you won't be specifying the Organization during login (letting the default login flow iterate thru Orgs), and want to get the user's Organization later on?

Comment: Yes. For example, if I were to roll my own login system with multi-tenancy, I'd expect the Organization to have many relationships with my user accounts. Likewise, a user would have a single (or multiple) relationships to an organization. That way, I could do Account.OrganizationId to managed the TenantId column in my own database. Currently, it looks like I can get that from the host header in .NET. I haven't figured out how to pass this information through the standard /login form, though.

Comment: Ah, missed the "group per organization model" part of your question at first. Just to clarify: you have your tenants modeled using the Stormpath Group resource?

Comment: Correct. I can get the system to work with the domain model where their tenant is retrieved and parsed out of the host. I'd just rather get it somehow from the Account context in my API. It seems like it'd be more clean and less reliant on the front-end. In any case, I have a ticket open as authentication seems to be broken entirely against my Stormpath account so I have no way of testing this further.

Comment: I think I already helped you solve this problem out-of-band of StackOverflow, but I wanted to circle back around and post an official answer for anyone else who might find it via Google. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible in Stormpath using a `namekey`.

**How to Create an `Organization`**

```
var bankOfAOrg = client.Instantiate<IOrganization>()
     .SetName("Bank of A")
     .SetNameKey("bank-of-a")
     .SetStatus(OrganizationStatus.Enabled);
```

Adding an Account Store to an Organization:

```
// With a reference to an IDirectory:
var newMapping = await bankOfAOrg.AddAccountStoreAsync(existingDirectory);

// Or simply by href:
newMapping = await bankOfAOrg.AddAccountStoreAsync("directory_href");
```

In order to be able to add Groups and Accounts to the Organization in the way mentioned above, we should also make sure that we mark this Account Store as our default for both Accounts and Groups:

```
newMapping.SetDefaultAccountStore(true)
.SetDefaultGroupStore(true);

await newMapping.SaveAsync();
```

Adding an Account to an Organization:

```
var chewie = client.Instantiate<IAccount>()
   .SetGivenName("Chewbacca")
   .SetSurname("the Wookiee")
   .SetUsername("rrwwgggh")
   .SetEmail("chewie@kashyyyk.rim")
   .SetPassword("Changeme123!");
   chewie.CustomData.Put("favoriteShip", "Millennium Falcon");

await bankOfAOrg.CreateAccountAsync(chewie);
```

For more info look [here](https://docs.stormpath.com/csharp/product-guide/latest/multitenancy.html?highlight=organization).

Answer (score 0):

You touched on this in your question, but the current story is that you'll get an `onk` claim in the user's access token if you specify the Organization during login.

For example:

```
var request = new PasswordGrantRequest
{
    Username = "nate@foo.bar",
    Password = "Secret123?",
    OrganizationNameKey = "acme-org"
}

var response = await application.ExecuteOauthRequestAsync(request);
// response.AccessTokenString will contain an onk claim
```

> Ideally, I'd like the user to be able to login without specifying their tenant as a subdomain or a field in the login form. Since it will go through my organization stores in order, I'd expect that to be feasible.

That's not currently feasible with the Organization object, but is feasible with the Group object, since you can enumerate the Account's Groups after the fact.

Disclaimer: I work at Stormpath.